# Eclipse add imports below comment

Tags: java, eclipse

When I'm creating Java files, I like to maintain a similar layout between all of my files, which looks something like this:

```
/*
 * ThisFile.java
 * Jamie Davies (2012)
 */

imports

package name

class
```

However, when Eclipse automatically adds appropriate import statements for me (which is a very handy feature), it always adds them to the very top of the file - resulting in my file comment being pushed down.

Is there any way to get Eclipse to automatically add imports at a certain position in the file - i.e, after my comment?

I've tried looking at the 'New Java Files' template, but there doesn't seem to be a $variable for important statements. I'm running Eclipse Juno (4.2.0) on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8).

*Edit:* It actually appears that after I've manually placed one import statement, Eclipse will automatically add others to the same location as the first.

Comment: However much you might like it this way, an `import` **before** a `package` declaration is illegal.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't even notice that I'd put them that way around in the post! My main focus was on getting the imports after the comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the `new java files` template, edit the present one to the following

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

Hope that helps. You could even try new variables by clicking on the `Insert Variable` button.

Answer (score 0):

add the first import by yourself and eclipse will automatically generate the others just following yours.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too. Is there any way to tell Eclipse to add the first import automatically though? It's a bit of a pain to have to manually add (or move) an import statement for every file I create.

Comment: I dont think there are other ways: it just the way how Eclipse works